# Probability theory : Event definition and Subset

Tags: probability-theory

In Probability theory, we define $Event$ like this
"Subset of Sample Space"

For Example, When we play Coin-toss game (just one-flip), then the sample space would be constructed:
$\{\{H\},\{T\}\}$

And there are just only two events in textbook explanation
1.Head  $\{H\}$
2.Tail  $\{T\}$

However, when we think about a 'subset', there is also $\{\{H\},\{T\}\}$!!

Then except 2, there are also the other events : $\{\{H\},\{T\}\}$, $\{ø\}$
but why the theory doesn't consider just above two as events..?? In definition, $\{\{H\},\{T\}\}$, $\{ø\}$ are also subset of sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using your book's notation, but usually we would say that the sample space (for flipping a coin) is $\{H,T\}$ (Note that $H$ and $T$ are presented as individual elements, not as sets). The elements of the sample space are ${\underline {\rm outcomes}}$ of the experiment. So this experiment has two outcomes: $H$ and $T$.

Events, as you noted, are subsets of the sample space. So the events in this situation are
$\emptyset, \{H\}, \{T\},$ and $\{H,T\}$.

By the way, what you wrote: $\{\emptyset\}$, is not an event.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, an *event* is defined as e subset of the sample space $\Omega$, while a *result* is defined as an element of $\Omega$. In your case, $H$ is a result, while $\{H\}$ and $\emptyset$ are events.

Either your book has a different definition, which is unlikely, or this part of the book is just wrong.